# Problema al recrear LineChartModel

Tags: primefaces

Buenas. Estoy intentando recrear una LineChartModel y no consigo que aparezca. Los datos se guardan bien en dateModel.addSeries(series).tampoco me da ningun tipo de error.

Si pruebo con el ejemplo de la pagina de primefaces funciona bien, pero comparando con el mio, no veo diferencias en la obtencion de valores.

dejo mi codigo:

```
private void createDateModel() {
    dateModel = new LineChartModel();
    LineChartSeries series = new LineChartSeries();
    series.setLabel("Series");

    List<Coupon> cupon = cuponBean.cuponesPorDia();
    List<Long> cuponCount = cuponBean.cuponesPorDiaCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < cupon.size(); i++){
        Date fecha = cupon.get(i).getPurchaseDatetime();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
        String fechaFormateada = sdf.format(fecha);
        int numeroCupones = Integer.parseInt(cuponCount.get(i).toString());
        series.set(fechaFormateada,numeroCupones);
    }
    dateModel.addSeries(series);         
    dateModel.setTitle("Zoom for Details");
    dateModel.setZoom(true);
    dateModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setLabel("Values");
    DateAxis axis = new DateAxis("Dates");
    axis.setTickAngle(-50);
    axis.setMax("2017-11-29");
    axis.setTickFormat("%b %#d, %y");
    dateModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axis);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fallo de novato (facepalm). El problema estaba en SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy"). cambiandolo a SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") ya funciona